# How to call another object's function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects in a JavaScript file index.js.

```
var obj1 = {
    function1: function() {
        // do something
        obj2.function2();
    }
};

var obj2 = {
    function2: function() {
        // do something
    }
};
```

I am calling function1() from an html file, like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    obj1.function1();
</script>
```

The problem is that the function2 on obj2 is not getting called.
**Why is function2 not getting called?**
 Content assistance in eclipse does not show the function at all when I do obj2.(ctrl space).
Is the syntax incorrect?

Comment: Well... How do you call it?

Comment: Show the function call.

Comment: Yeah, just removed. Seemed similar but wasn't

Comment: `function2` *is* being called. What makes you think it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't being called because `function1` isn't being called.

Add `obj1.function1()` to the end of the code and it works.

You should also add some code to provide a visible effect to `function2` so that you can tell when it is called.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/udZYn/)

Answer (score 0):

If you call obj1.function(); before obj2 is declared, it should throw an Error as you cannot call a method form an undefined Object. I see no other reason why it wouldn't work...

Answer (score -1):

you can do with your same code but just call function1 after declaration

```
var obj1 = {
   function1: function() {
      // do something
      obj2.function2();
   }
};

var obj2 = {
   function2: function() {
       // do something
       alert("obj2");
   }
};

obj1.function1();
```

You can check it in http://jsfiddle.net/vVKKZ/

because when you call function1 at that time obj1 was not declared so it is undefined at that time.

Comment: The code I have shown is in a JavaScript file. I am calling function1() from a html file. I added the html code to the question above. Please look.

Comment: just try to call function1 from end of the body tag.

Comment: index.js script adding in head tag and calling script at bottom of the body.

Comment: You mean just before the </body> tag?

Comment: Yes just before </body> tag